# Scala 2.10 reflection: ClassSymbol.isCaseClass works in scala console but not in script/app

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I am playing around with reflection in Scala 2.10.0-M7 and stumbled upon the `ClassSymbol.isCaseClass` method which behaves like expected in the scala console but not when executed as a java application or as a scala script.

I've defined `TestScript.scala` like this:

```
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror

case class TestCase(foo: String)

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val classSymbol = currentMirror.reflect(new TestCase("foo")).symbol
    val isCaseClass = classSymbol.isCaseClass
    println(s"isCaseClass: $isCaseClass")
  }
}

Test.main(Array())
```

If I execute it on the command line calling

```
$ scala TestScript.scala
```

I get this output:

```
isCaseClass: false
```

If I instead input the code into the interactive scala shell or load it like this:

```
scala> :load TestScript.scala
```

I get the following correct output:

```
Loading TestScript.scala...
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
defined class TestCase
defined module Test
isCaseClass: true
```

If I compile it and execute it as a standard Java app I get `false` as result for `ClassSymbol.isCase` again.

What am I missing? What are the differences between the scala console environment and the java runtime environment? How can I get the correct result in a real application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6277

```
val classSymbol = cm.reflect(new TestCase("foo")).symbol

{ classSymbol.typeSignature }
val isCaseClass = classSymbol.isCaseClass
println(s"isCaseClass: $isCaseClass")
```

Edit: to answer your last question, you wouldn't be using a milestone in a real application. :)

Upd. Fixed since Scala 2.10.0-RC1.

Comment: It works if executed as a java application, but surprisingly not if executed as a scala script. But as the script was only for trying around this is no blocker for me. Regarding your edit: of course I don't use a milestone for a productive app ;-) With "real" I only meant a compiled artifact (e.g. jar) running on the JVM.