# Why does Scala reflection work inside an object but not at the top level of a script?

Tags: scala, reflection

This script uses reflection to find the type signature of a constructor. It contains the same code inside an object and at the top level:

```
// Scala 2.11.1
case class Dirigible(cubicFeet: Int)

object Object {
  val u = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val ctor = u.weakTypeOf[Dirigible].decl(u.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).typeSignature
  def run() {
    println(ctor)
  }
}

Object.run()

val u = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val ctor = u.weakTypeOf[Dirigible].decl(u.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).typeSignature
println(ctor)
```

Here is the output:

```
(cubicFeet: Int)$anon.this.Dirigible
<notype>
```

Why does the top-level code fail while the code inside `Object` works?

The same failure occurs if I put the `println` inside a top-level `def` and call it from the top level.

The top-level code works if I run the file in the REPL via `scala -i refltest.scala`. That's to be expected, since the REPL puts everything into an object. What I don't understand is, why does code's being inside an object affect the results of reflection?

Answer (score 1):

The script runner wraps your code in a local anonymous class; your code is run as part of the initializer.

I don't know why that breaks reflection, but it's a duplicate of [this question from a couple of years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12377046/1296806).  That was edited to say the problem was fixed, but I don't see it working.

As a workaround, wrap your code in a block:

```
locally {
val u = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val ctor = u.weakTypeOf[Dirigible].decl(u.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).typeSignature
println(ctor)
}
```

Maybe it has to do with init order and how the local class is compiled.

Comment: @eugene-burmako might be interested.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and it works. And thanks for showing me `locally`: I hadn't heard of that before.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako's answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828246/macro-implementation-reference-has-wrong-shape-in-the-scala-documentation-exam?lq=1) leads me to wonder if the problem is that `u` is not a static object. Indeed, when I replace each reference to `u` with `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`, it works. Still a little baffling, though, since `u` refers to the same `universe` object, which presumably is static.

Comment: Yes, I was going to post the -Xprint output, too. Here, it's not the u value but maybe the "stable path" it's inspecting.

Comment: @BenKovitz What if you do `val u: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.type = scala.reflect.runtime.universe`?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Same result: `<notype>`.